# How can you make an interface GAP for Haskell?

Tags: haskell, gap-system

I need to use GAP with Haskell. How can you make an interface for Haskell to call GAP's functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a project [HPC-GAP](http://www-circa.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/hpcgap.php) that uses a version of GUM, a run-time system for Glasgow parallel Haskell, to provide an interface to GAP and allow running it on clusters or Grids. [This paper](http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/ansatte/berthold/papers/cashIFL10-withCopyright.pdf) describes how to call GAP from Haskell and the other way round.

Comment: Now Hets and Gap can be used with Haskell. Haskell is the King.

Comment: Gap can use singular, do HPC-GAP include Singular or its other packages?

Comment: You would need to double check the version of GAP used as the software is rather experimental. I've added another link above to a paper that describes the interface.